# Use CONCAT() to merge column values into a column

Tags: mysql, if-statement, concatenation

I want to turn certain columns values into columns using IF() Function
and CONCAT() Function , but i can't get it right somehow . 
After i run this sql :

```
SELECT 

IF( meta_key =  'property_id',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_id,
IF( meta_key =  'property_contract',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_contract,
IF( meta_key =  'property_agents',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_agents


FROM wp_postmeta

WHERE property_id !='faslse'
and property_agents = 'John Doe'
```

I get this error :**1054 - Unknown column 'property_id' in 'where clause'**

EDIT :

I am trying this query but returns 0 rows ...

```
select *

from
(  select
  IF( meta_key =  'property_id',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_id,
  IF( meta_key =  'property_contract',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_contract,
  IF( meta_key =  'property_agents',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_agents

from
  wp_postmeta) p


WHERE 
 p.property_id != 'false'
  and p.property_contract != 'false'
  and p.property_agents!= 'false'
```

Comment: about the edit: the query will return 0 rows because all three values won't be != 'false' at the same time which has to be expected: if meta_key value is property_id, meta_value and property_value will be false and the same goes for any other value

Comment: @fthiella how can i solve this kind of situation ?

Comment: I will update my answer, it's not clear from the question but I think I know what's the problem

Answer (score 1):

The alias is applied after the where clause, so you have two choices, repeat the IF clause:

```
select
  IF( meta_key =  'property_id',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_id,
  IF( meta_key =  'property_contract',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_contract,
  IF( meta_key =  'property_agents',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) AS property_agents

from
  wp_postmeta
where
  IF( meta_key =  'property_id',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) !='faslse'
  and IF( meta_key =  'property_agents',  CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value),  'false' ) = 'John Doe'
```

or use a subquery:

```
select *
from
  (
     select
       IF(...) as property_id,
       IF(...) as property_agents
     from
       wp_postmeta
  ) s
where
  s.property_id != 'false'
  and s.property_agents = 'John Doe'
```

the query could be optimized in various ways but this depends on your requirements.

**Edit**

It's not clear from the question, but I think that the problem you want to solve is a little different. I suppose you have a `post_id` field in your `wp_postmeta` table and I suppose that the properties for each post are in different rows. With the following query you can get the id, contract and agents for a single post:

```
select
  post_id,
  max(case when meta_key = 'property_id' then CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value) end) as property_id,
  max(case when meta_key = 'property_contract' then CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value) end) as property_contract,
  max(case when meta_key = 'property_id' then CONCAT(meta_key, ' ', meta_value) end) as property_agents
from
  wp_postmeta
group by
  post_id
```

then you can just add filters with having:

```
having
  property_agents='property_agents John Doe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
WHERE property_id !='faslse'
```

Please Use this, Also correct spelling from `faslse` to `false`

```
HAVING property_id !='faslse'
```

Copied from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

> You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses

Answer (score 0):

Please use "HAVING" clause on the behalf of "WHERE" clause

Comment: Thank you for `POSTING` Duplicate answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42063706/2893413

Answer (score 0):

The problem was like @fthiella said that the values
could not be non false at the same time because the i was selecting the same
column to do the IF() statements . So after some thinking i came up with this :

```
SELECT 
p_id.property_id ,
p_agents.property_agents,
p_contract.property_contract
FROM

(SELECT post_id , IF( meta_key =  'property_contract', meta_value ,  'false' ) AS property_contract FROM wp_postmeta HAVING  property_contract != 'false' )p_contract
INNER join
(SELECT post_id , IF( meta_key =  'property_agents', meta_value ,  'false' ) AS property_agents FROM wp_postmeta HAVING  property_agents != 'false' )p_agents
ON
p_contract.post_id = p_agents.post_id
INNER join
(SELECT post_id , IF( meta_key =  'property_id', meta_value ,  'false' ) AS property_id FROM wp_postmeta HAVING  property_id != 'false' )p_id
ON
p_contract.post_id = p_id.post_id
GROUP BY p_contract.post_id Order by p_contract.post_id
```

And it works. Thank you all for trying and helping.